# Block Typescript Auto-complete in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.2.4 Ultimate.

It seems that fairly recently the default auto-complete option when typing 'throw new Err' has changed from the standard Javascript Error class, to a typescript one.

[image]

Not only that, the standard Javascript error class doesn't even appear in the dropdown.

It makes no sense that it would suggest a Typescript class in a JS file, and even worse, no non-Typescript option at all.

After digging through the auto-completion settings and the auto-import settings, there doesn't seem to be any way to change this. It looks like it's sourcing this Typescript Error class from the Javascript plugin itself, so there is no way for me to eliminate the source without losing Javascript support.

The only workaround I've found is implementing my own exception class with a different name, and using that everywhere. But that doesn't work for all cases, so I end up just typing out the entire thing every time, which seems dumb in a fancy IDE like this.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior - since 2017.3 IDEA uses the `lib.*.d.ts` files from [Typescript repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib) to power its code completion for standard JavaScript objects and methods. These files are now packaged inside IDE and updated regularly to keep libraries in sync with APIs changes.

Previously we used and maintained our own definition files that were incomplete and not always accurate. Transition to the new definition files has made completion and quick docs more accuirate, complete and maintainable